# Send Email From Alternate/Shared Mailbox with Webservices.ExchangeService

Tags: .net, vb.net, email, exchangewebservices

I have searched A LOT and can only find how to obtain inbox messages from a shared/alternate email account/mailbox in Exchange but I cannot find how to send FROM a shared mailbox.

The basic need is that it appears to the recipient of the email that the email came from 'email2@domain.com' (which is a shared mailbox I have access to) and not my primary account I login to ('email1@domain.com'). Also, the sent email should be saved in the shared mailbox's sent folder.

The way exchange works is that you sign into your primary account and you can open other shared mailboxes from within that main account (provided you have rights to it). If I use the code below, it still sends from my email1@domain.com.

```
service = New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013)
service.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(username, _pw)
service.TraceEnabled = True
service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All

service.AutodiscoverUrl("email2@domain.com", AddressOf ValidateRedirectionUrlCallback)

Dim message As New EmailMessage(service)
message.Subject = subject
message.Body = body
For Each Item In _to
   message.ToRecipients.Add(Item)
Next

For Each Item In AttachmentPaths
    message.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(Item)
Next

message.SendAndSaveCopy()
```

Im starting to think maybe the message object has to have certain properties set to look like it is coming from email1 but is actually sent from my main account, but is that the official/best way? If so, what properties do I set to make it appear that it is coming from another mailbox?

I would assume I would then save the message manually to the saved folder of the shared mailbox.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into using `SMTPClient`?

Comment: Just a wild guess: may sharing a mailbox is not enough and you need 'delegate access'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my own issue by just setting the 'From' field to what I want the recipient to see the email coming from and adding the same address to the list of reply to list. I also had to get receive/send access on the shared folder, I originally was only given read access which cause an exception in the `saveandsendcopy` method.

Code below.

```
Public Function Create(ByRef emailaddress As String, ByRef username As String, ByRef _domain As String, ByRef _pw As String) As Boolean
    Try

        service = New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013)
        service.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(username, _pw)
        service.TraceEnabled = True
        service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All

        service.AutodiscoverUrl(emailaddress, AddressOf ValidateRedirectionUrlCallback)

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try

End Function

Public Function Send(ByRef subject As String, ByRef body As String, ByRef _to As List(Of String), ByRef AttachmentPaths As List(Of String), ByRef from As String) As Boolean
    Try

        Dim message As New EmailMessage(service)
        message.From = New EmailAddress(from)
        message.ReplyTo.Add(from)

        message.Subject = subject

        message.Body = body

        For Each Item In _to
            message.ToRecipients.Add(Item)
        Next

        For Each Item In AttachmentPaths
            ' Add a file attachment by using a stream.
            Dim theStream As New FileStream(Item, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)

            Dim pathparts As String() = Item.Split("\")

            ' The streamed file attachment is named FourthAttachment.txt.
            message.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(pathparts(pathparts.Count - 1), theStream)

        Next
        message.SendAndSaveCopy()

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try


End Function
```

I still need to find out how to save the message to the sent folder but have not found that out yet.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code if you wish to save the message to the sent folder for the shared account (in C#):

```
var folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, new Mailbox("email2@domain.com"));
message.SendAndSaveCopy(folderId);
```

I have not tried the above code but let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: This help me to save the email message in sent item for shared mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

I was just coming here to post my resolution with the final code. Since the server doesn't allow impersonation, I use the following code (which I found [here](http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2010/12/exchange-saving-mails-to-delegated-user%27s-mailbox-with-ews-managed-api)). What messed me up for so long is that the example in that link uses more than just the email of where you want to save the document. I didn't think to just provide the email itself, since the example the author gave had a lot extra in it.

```
Public Function Send(ByRef subject As String, ByRef body As String, ByRef _to As List(Of String), ByRef AttachmentPaths As List(Of String), ByRef from As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim message As New EmailMessage(service)
        message.From = New EmailAddress(from)
        message.ReplyTo.Add(from)

        message.Subject = subject

        message.Body = body

        For Each Item In _to
            message.ToRecipients.Add(Item)
        Next

        For Each Item In AttachmentPaths
            ' Add a file attachment by using a stream.
            Dim theStream As New FileStream(Item, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)

            Dim pathparts As String() = Item.Split("\")

            ' The streamed file attachment is named FourthAttachment.txt.
            message.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(pathparts(pathparts.Count - 1), theStream)
        Next

        message.Save(New FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Drafts, New Mailbox(from)))
        message.SendAndSaveCopy(New FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, New Mailbox(from)))

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```